# Not getting correct media position

Tags: android, chromecast

Trying to get the current position of the track playing on the receiver but

remoteMediaPlayer.getApproximateStreamPosition()
(return 0)

and

remoteMediaPlayer.getMediaStatus().getStreamPosition()
(updates only if we trigger onStatusUpdated())

fail to give accurate value.

Comment: What receiver are you using? If you check out CastVideos-android sample, or the DemoCastPlayer sample from the SDK distribution, you would notice that the media position gets updated as expected, so you need to see what is the difference between those and your code.

Answer (score -2):

In my experience `remoteMediaPlayer.getApproximateStreamPosition()` will always return 0 if the duration is 0. Verify that your stream has a valid duration greater than zero.